# React - Material-ui : Autocomplete on words that aren't the first in a sentence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement autocomplete on hashtags for my webapp, so typing #h would bring up a menu with #hello, #hope, etc etc. As im using material-ui everywhere else it would be great if i could just use the autocomplete-component, but it only works on the first word typed in the AutoComplete-box. In other words, it can autocomplete "#Hello what a great day", but if i type more than one word the autocomplete is disabled, so "It sure is a great day #Hello" won't auto complete the #Hello. None of their examples can do this either. Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with the material-ui components:

```
<div style={{position:'relative'}}>

      <AutoComplete
        hintText="Type anything"
        dataSource={['#hello','#how','#are','#you']}
        ref={ref=>this.autocompleteRef=ref}
        searchText={this.state.searchText}
        onNewRequest={this.onNewRequest}
        textFieldStyle={{visibility:'hidden'}}
        style={{position:'absolute',top:'0',left:'0'}}
      />
      <TextField
        value={this.state.fullText || ''}
        hintText="fullText"
        onChange={this.myTextChange}
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
```

And the functions should look something like:

```
myTextChange=(event)=>{
  let fullText = event.target.value,searchText;
  let hashTaggingIndex = this.hashTaggingIndex;
  if(hashTaggingIndex && hashTaggingIndex>-1){
    if(fullText[fullText.length-1]===' ') this.hashTaggingIndex = -1;
    else {
      searchText = fullText.substring(hashTaggingIndex+1,fullText.length);
    }
  } else if(fullText[fullText.length-1]==='#') { 
     this.hashTaggingIndex=fullText.length-1;
  }
  this.setState({fullText,searchText});
  if(this.autocompleteRef && hashTaggingIndex && hashTaggingIndex>-1){
    this.autocompleteRef.handleChange(event);
   }
};

onNewRequest=(value)=>{
  let fullText=this.state.fullText;
  fullText = fullText.substring(0,this.hashTaggingIndex) + value;
  this.setState({fullText})
};
```

Have fun:)

Comment: This is super nice, but i have a new problem - when an option is selected, the focus is removed from the textfield and the keyboard disappears. I tried fiddling around with the onNewRequest to manually set the focus again, but i've not had any success. Also, is there any way to make it start displaying options as soon as the user starts typing '#' instead of '#'+ some letter?

Comment: @Zazz all these components have native events that can be extended like `onFocus` or `onBlur` , try manipulate them. so for example (and not the best one), you could hold a ref to the TextField as well and focus it from the onNewRequest like `this.textFieldRef.focus()`

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [Filter](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete) function to extract only words beginning with #.

**Edit

@Zazz It is possible, you could implement something like:

```
myFilter=(searchText, key) => {
if(this.hashTaggingIndex && this.hashTaggingIndex>-1){
  if(searchText[searchText.length-1]===' ') this.hashTaggingIndex = -1;
  else {
    return key.indexOf(searchText.substring(this.hashTaggingIndex+1,searchText.length))!==-1
  }
}else{
  if(searchText[searchText.length-1]==='#') this.hashTaggingIndex=searchText.length-1;
}};
```

But you need to consider that autocomplete of material-ui does not expose a direct method to prevent from overriding the previous content with the selected autocomplete item. So you need to mask it with another input field (using `position:absolute` and hide the autocomplete `<input>` tag) so the user continues to see its previous text.

We had to implement something similar to yours, and decided to go with a simple input field and implement the auto-complete drop down ourselves.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - the auto-complete functionality still goes away after the first word is typed

Comment: Thanks! Im starting to think i'm better off doing what you did, though it would be nice to bundle it with the existing material-ui input field

Comment: @Zazz added another example using m-ui components only